# What is the Epiphany hat for?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I just received the Epiphany hat, but I can't make sense of the description:

> La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte

Which translates from Italian to:

> La Befana comes by night with broken shoes all

And here is the [Wiki for La Befana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana), "an old woman who delivers gifts to children throughout Italy on Epiphany Eve".

...but what does this all mean? Why did I receive the hat?!

Comment: According to the votes on this and related questions, people are really passionate about their hats for whatever reason. Don't sweat it. As for the duplicate, which was asked three minutes earlier: that one had a pretty bad title, I fixed it.

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow that all happened so fast! Oh well :-)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The supposed duplicate asks why the name is in Italian, not what the hat is for.

Comment: And yet, in the process of explaining why the name is in Italian, the answer answers this very question!

Comment: @CodyGray The hat is awarded for posting or voting on January 6. Maybe I'm overlooking it, but I don't see that in the answer over there. The way I read this question, OP asks why the hat is awarded.

Comment: To answer the question: the epiphany hat is for today because we are the epiphany day. But yeah I think it's not the answer you want right ? (Epiphany is a Christian event [link wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday))